# How do I adjust a desired rotation by the model's current orientation to the camera using quaternions (Three.js)?

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation, three.js, quaternions

I have a Three.js web application with a single model.  I use the mouse to rotate the model.  This is done by recording the amount of X/Y movement over time between mouse down and mouse up events and using the delta X/Y values to *rotate the model* around the desired axis, (X Y or Z).  I do *not* change the camera perspective or orientation.

For mouse Y movement, I rotate the model around the X axis, rotating in the YZ plane.  When the model is in it's original state with a quaternion value of (0, 0, 0 1), this works great since I want the *top* of the model to *rotate away from the camera* (me) when I move the mouse *up* and *towards the camera* when I move the mouse *down*.

However, I of course lose this movement perspective after the model is rotated.  For example, if I rotate the model a full 180 degrees around the Y-axis (flip it horizontally), the perceived motion inverts.  Moving the mouse *up* moves the model *towards* the camera and moving it *down* moves the model *away* from the camera.

My question is, **how can I adjust the rotation operations to maintain the desired *perceived* movement, regardless of the change in the model's quaternion value due to movement?**  That is, what steps/operations do I need to take to compensate for the model's current orientation given its current quaternion, so I get the same perceived movement of the model when moving the mouse?

I use the code below to rotate the model, where *object* is the model, *axis* is the desired axis (pure X, Y, or Z), and *radians* is the desired angle of rotation:

```
function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians)
{
    var rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);

    object.matrix.multiply(rotObjectMatrix);

    object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the rotation from the point of view of the rotated object so you need to left-multiply the rotation.

So if the final MVP matrix is from `perspective*view*model` then you need to insert the rotation between the model and view matrices.

```
function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians)
{
    var rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);

    rotObjectMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);

    object.matrix = rotObjectMatrix;

    object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
}
```